# Is it possible to create the Azure AD user account using federated domain via graph api?

Tags: azure

Is it possible to create the Azure AD user account using federated domain via graph api? I am encountered this error message 'SourceAnchor is a required property for creation of a federated user.' We are using adfs to sync user account between on-premised AD and Azure AD cloud.

Comment: Small correction, ADFS is not used to sync user data. Azure AD Connect is used for that, it should be installed on some of your servers. You are probably using ADFS to sign in (AAD redirects you to ADFS login page which then returns you to AAD, which then returns you to app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it’s not possible. Federated accounts can only be created in the system of origin - in this case AD